# Excel - Format value (mask) VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to format a cell value with VBA.

if use Record Macro :

```
Selection.NumberFormatLocal = """mask"";""mask"";""mask"";""mask"""
```

I want to mask cell with value in Cell or Textbox.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim dgstring1, dgstring2, dgstring3, dgstring4 As String

'Ex Sheet1.Range("F26") = "Mask"

    dgstring1 = Sheet1.Range("F26") '
    dgstring2 = Sheet1.Range("F26")
    dgstring3 = Sheet1.Range("F26")
    dgstring4 = Sheet1.Range("F26")
    dgstring = "dgstring1;dgstring2;dgstring3;dgstring4"
    Selection.NumberFormatLocal = dgstring

End Sub
```

Comment: Declaring variables in that way, all of them are of the type `Variant` and only the last one is a `String`. `dgstring` is not even declared. For giving a valute to this variable you only build a string as it can be seen. Do you want using the values collected from the above ranges? Then, how would you want a specific value to look with that peculiar format? Please edit your question and show us an example value in `General` format, followed by the same value in the format you need...

Comment: Thank for your quick response, but still an error even though the variable has been replaced with Variant and the last one is a String. The Error is "Unable to set the NumberFormatLocal....

Comment: Correcting the variable declarations should not solve your problem. Anyhow, I did not want to say that they must be `Variant` type! I explained what your code does. I asked some clarification questions but you did not do anything, from this point of view. If I do not understand what is to be done, I cannot help... Can you show us what I asked in my previous comment?

Comment: Is it so difficult to edit your question and show us what you want accomplishing? It looks that I am more interested than you in solving your problem... Are you sure that you know what you want?

Answer (score 0):

[Detail below: General Format with Custom Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkJ0e.jpg)